# TC551001-70 Eagle library

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, library, socket

I am looking for an Eagle libray containing the **TC551001-70** RAM IC. I have looked for a 32 pin DIP socket but also haven’t been able to find. Any help would be great, thank you.

Datasheet: http://www.datasheet39.com/PDF/1096980/TC551001CF-70-datasheet.html

Answer (score 1):

I search on my computer and I already have the 32 pin DIP footprint in my Eagle library.

I share via this link that's from my personal one drive:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!At8VA9z1pAjFgQi8zXygfRh8uccT?e=PGK3GB

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect

Answer (score 0):

There are two 32 pin packages for that memory. Which one? You can fairly easily make your own symbol and footprint for that device with Eagle.

Or just look for a 32 pin SOP/TSOP library symbol - doesn't have to be that specific device. The use that as a starting point for creating your own.

Comment: DIP32 socket needed. Already looked for just the socket, couldn’t find a 32 pin DIP anywhere… maybe I’ve missed it though. And I know I could make my own I just thought I’d ask first

Comment: @tom - I don’t think you will find a socket, you ma find a Sop/tsop to DIP converter that can then fit into a socket. There are other devices with SOP footprints, I made one for an SRAM once. You just clone it then change the signal names.